# Filter a table in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter

Hy,

I have a table with names in column A and dates in row 3.

Now I want to filter the person that are present at a given date. I cannot figure out which function I have to use. I was very succesful wirh the function FILTER. But I cannot figure out how to apply the filter range according the current date.

Link of the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ECqqZ0VeyECYwuF_fL1XB3tSFjnnftHNFKV_Pkas7P8/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use nested `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(A4:A7,FILTER(B4:E7,B3:E3=B1)="x")
```

[image]